# Function in jquery is not defined

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener

Anyone please help me,
I Have an project build with Code Igniter 3,
So the schematic is :
I Have 2 file view, i caled formAdd.php and detail.php
and 1 file controller i named is Uangmuka.php

In formAdd.php i use the select option, when the select option change, i send the request with ajax to Uangmuka.php -> method : getDetailSPB, my request is detail data based on id i sent, and the return data in the form of html elements I insert using : $("#table_temp").html(data);

The script is as below :

```
 $('#no_spb').change(function() {
            $("#btn-save").addClass("hide");
            $("#btn-save-verifikasi").addClass("hide");

            var id_spb = $("#no_spb").val();
            var acc_dp = $("#no_spb option:selected").data("acc_dp");
            var nama_supplier = $("#no_spb option:selected").data("nama_supplier");
            // var id_barang = $("#nama_barang_add").data("id_barang");
            // alert(acc_dp);
            $("#supplier").val(nama_supplier);
            $("#uang_muka").val(acc_dp);
            $("#uang_muka").select2({
                theme: "bootstrap4"
            });
            // $('#uang_muka option[value="' + acc_dp + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?= base_url("admin/Uangmuka/getDetailSPB") ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id_spb: id_spb
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#table_temp").html(data); //inner HTML to id : table_temp
                    $("#btn-save").removeClass("hide");
                    $("#btn-save-verifikasi").removeClass("hide");
                }
            });
        });
```

In the Controller i get the request like this :

```
$id_spb = $this->input->post('id_spb');
        $detail_spb = $this->Pengadaan_model->getDetailSPBDP($id_spb);

        // foreach ($detail_spb as $col) {
        //     echo $col["nama_barang"] . "<br/>";
        // }
        $data = [
            "detail_spb" => $detail_spb
        ];
        $this->load->view("trx_uang_muka/detail", $data);
```

The script above successfully displays data based on detail.php into formAdd.php

The script in detail.php is as below :

```
 <!-- Table SPB -->
 <div class="col">
     <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h6 class="card-title">
                 Data SPB
             </h6>
         </div>
         <!-- /.card-header -->
         <div class="card-body">
             <table class="table" id="table-temporary">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                         <th>Nama Barang</th>
                         <th>Qty</th>
                         <th>Satuan</th>
                         <th>Aksi</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                     <?php
                        $i = 1;
                        foreach ($detail_spb as $col) : ?>
                         <tr>
                             <td><?= $i++; ?></td>
                             <td><?= $col["nama_barang"]; ?></td>
                             <td><?= $col["qty"]; ?></td>
                             <td><?= $col["satuan"]; ?></td>
                             <td>
                                 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-end align-items-baseline">
                                     <div class="col p-0">
                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add" data-id_spb="<?= $col["id_spb"]; ?>" data-no_spb="<?= $col["no_spb"]; ?>" data-id_rab="<?= $col["id_rab"]; ?>" data-id_barang="<?= $col["id_barang"]; ?>" data-nama_barang="<?= $col["nama_barang"]; ?>" data-qty="<?= $col["qty"]; ?>" data-satuan="<?= $col["satuan"]; ?>" data-harga_rab="<?= $col["harga_rab"]; ?>" data-acc_persediaan="<?= $col["acc_persediaan"]; ?>" data-id_supplier="<?= $col["id_supplier"]; ?>" data-nama_supplier="<?= $col["nama_supplier"]; ?>"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.card -->
 </div>
 <!-- Table uang muka Temporary -->
 <div class="col">
     <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h6 class="card-title">
                 Data Uang Muka
             </h6>
         </div>
         <!-- /.card-header -->
         <div class="card-body" id="table_uang_muka">

         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.card -->
 </div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_uang_muka" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah Barang</h1>
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col">
                         <label for='nama_barang_add'>Nama Barang</label>
                         <input type='text' name='nama_barang_add' id='nama_barang_add' class='form-control' readonly>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col">
                         <label for='qty_add'>Qty</label>
                         <input type='number' name='qty_add' id='qty_add' class='form-control' placeholder='Qty'>
                         <span class="hide" id="qty_add_error"><small class="text-danger">Qty Tidak Boleh Kosong</small></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col">
                         <label for='satuan_add'>Satuan</label>
                         <input type='text' name='satuan_add' id='satuan_add' class='form-control' placeholder='Satuan' readonly>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col">
                         <label for='harga_rab'>Harga RAB</label>
                         <input type='text' name='harga_rab_add' id='harga_rab_add' class='form-control' readonly>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col">
                         <label for='harga_inv'>Harga Invoice</label>
                         <input type='number' name='harga_inv_add' id='harga_inv_add' class='form-control' placeholders='Harga Invoice'>
                         <span class="hide" id="harga_inv_add_error"><small class="text-danger">Harga Invoice Tidak Boleh Kosong Atau "NOL"</small></span>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add-modal">Add</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         window.data_barang = [];

         function delete_spb(index) { //Fungsi delete data barang pada sppb
             window.data_barang.splice(index, 1);

             var table = '<table class="table table-striped">';

             table += '<thead>';
             table += '<tr>';
             table += '<th>No</th>';
             table += '<th>Nama Barang</th>';
             table += '<th>Qty</th>';
             table += '<th>Satuan</th>';
             table += '<th>Harga RAB</th>';
             table += '<th>Harga Inv</th>';
             table += '<th>Aksi</th>';
             table += '</tr>';
             table += '</thead>';

             table += '<tbody>';
             var i = 0;
             var index = 0;
             window.data_barang.forEach((barang) => {
                 i++;
                 table += '<tr>';
                 table += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
                 table += '<td>' + barang[2] + '</td>';
                 table += '<td>' + barang[3] + '</td>';
                 table += '<td>' + barang[4] + '</td>';
                 table += '<td>' + barang[5] + '</td>';
                 table += '<td>' + barang[6] + '</td>';
                 table += '<td> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_sppb" onclick="delete_spb(' + index + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button> </td>';
                 table += '</tr>';
                 index++;
             });
             table += '</tbody>';

             table += '</table>';

             $("#table_uang_muka").html(table);
         };
         $('.btn-add').click(function() { //Tombol add di table RKBJ
             $("#nama_barang_add").removeData("id_barang");
             $("#nama_barang_add").removeData("perkiraan");

             $("#nama_barang_add").val($(this).data("nama_barang"));
             $("#nama_barang_add").data("id_barang", $(this).data("id_barang"));
             $("#nama_barang_add").data("perkiraan", $(this).data("acc_persediaan"));
             $("#harga_rab_add").val($(this).data("harga_rab"));
             $("#harga_inv_add").val($(this).data("harga_rab"));
             $("#qty_add").val($(this).data("qty"));
             $("#satuan_add").val($(this).data("satuan"));
             $("#modal_uang_muka").modal("show");
         });

         $("#btn-add-modal").click(function() { // Tombol add di Modal
             $("#qty_add_error").addClass("hide")
             $("harga_inv_add_error").addClass("hide");

             var id_barang = $("#nama_barang_add").data("id_barang");
             var perkiraan = $("#nama_barang_add").data("perkiraan");
             var nama_barang = $("#nama_barang_add").val();
             var qty = $("#qty_add").val();
             var satuan = $("#satuan_add").val();
             var harga_rab = $("#harga_rab_add").val();
             var harga_inv = $("#harga_inv_add").val();

             // insert(id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang);
             if (qty == "" || harga_inv == "" || harga_inv == 0) {
                 if (qty == "") {
                     $("#qty_add_error").removeClass("hide");
                 }
                 if (harga_inv == "" || harga_inv == 0) {
                     $("#harga_inv_add_error").removeClass("hide");
                 }
             } else {
                 window.data_barang.push([id_barang, perkiraan, nama_barang, qty, satuan, harga_rab, harga_inv]);
                 console.table(window.data_barang);

                 var table = '<table class="table table-striped">';

                 table += '<thead>';
                 table += '<tr>';
                 table += '<th>No</th>';
                 table += '<th>Nama Barang</th>';
                 table += '<th>Qty</th>';
                 table += '<th>Satuan</th>';
                 table += '<th>Harga RAB</th>';
                 table += '<th>Harga Inv</th>';
                 table += '<th>Aksi</th>';
                 table += '</tr>';
                 table += '</thead>';

                 table += '<tbody>';
                 var i = 0;
                 var index = 0;
                 window.data_barang.forEach((barang) => {
                     i++;
                     table += '<tr>';
                     table += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[2] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[3] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[4] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[5] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[6] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_sppb" onclick="delete_spb(' + index + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button> </td>';
                     table += '</tr>';
                     index++;
                 });
                 table += '</tbody>';

                 table += '</table>';

                 $("#table_uang_muka").html(table);
                 $("#harga_inv_add").val("");
                 $("#modal_uang_muka").modal("hide");
             }

         });

     });
 </script>
```

In the detail.php script above i append html script to html element caled table_uang_muka,
like this:

```
  $("#btn-add-modal").click(function() { // Tombol add di Modal
             $("#qty_add_error").addClass("hide")
             $("harga_inv_add_error").addClass("hide");

             var id_barang = $("#nama_barang_add").data("id_barang");
             var perkiraan = $("#nama_barang_add").data("perkiraan");
             var nama_barang = $("#nama_barang_add").val();
             var qty = $("#qty_add").val();
             var satuan = $("#satuan_add").val();
             var harga_rab = $("#harga_rab_add").val();
             var harga_inv = $("#harga_inv_add").val();

             // insert(id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang, id_barang);
             if (qty == "" || harga_inv == "" || harga_inv == 0) {
                 if (qty == "") {
                     $("#qty_add_error").removeClass("hide");
                 }
                 if (harga_inv == "" || harga_inv == 0) {
                     $("#harga_inv_add_error").removeClass("hide");
                 }
             } else {
                 window.data_barang.push([id_barang, perkiraan, nama_barang, qty, satuan, harga_rab, harga_inv]);
                 console.table(window.data_barang);

                 var table = '<table class="table table-striped">';

                 table += '<thead>';
                 table += '<tr>';
                 table += '<th>No</th>';
                 table += '<th>Nama Barang</th>';
                 table += '<th>Qty</th>';
                 table += '<th>Satuan</th>';
                 table += '<th>Harga RAB</th>';
                 table += '<th>Harga Inv</th>';
                 table += '<th>Aksi</th>';
                 table += '</tr>';
                 table += '</thead>';

                 table += '<tbody>';
                 var i = 0;
                 var index = 0;
                 window.data_barang.forEach((barang) => {
                     i++;
                     table += '<tr>';
                     table += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[2] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[3] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[4] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[5] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td>' + barang[6] + '</td>';
                     table += '<td> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_sppb" onclick="delete_spb(' + index + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button> </td>';
                     table += '</tr>';
                     index++;
                 });
                 table += '</tbody>';

                 table += '</table>';

                 $("#table_uang_muka").html(table);
                 $("#harga_inv_add").val("");
                 $("#modal_uang_muka").modal("hide");
             }

         });
```

at the $("#btn-add-modal").click(function() {}); above i added a table html to #table_uang_muka, and you can see the following one line of code :

```
table += '<td> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_sppb" onclick="delete_spb(' + index + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button> </td>';
```

i added the td with onclick attribut caled delete_spb(' + index + ') like this :

```
onclick="delete_spb(' + index + ')"
```

But the delete_spb function is not working and i get the error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: delete_spb is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (formTambah:1:1)

whereas, i had declared the delete_spb function in my script

Thanks in advance, and I hope someone can help me solve this problem

I Try declared the delete_spb function, but stil not working